# Razor + JS Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I have this code:

```
var tempPath = "@Path.GetTempPath()";
var blobURL = tempPath + "image.jpg";
```

I get this error when I inspect my page:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

And this line is underlined:

```
var tempPath = "C:\Windows\TEMP\";
```

It's probably a stupid solution but i can't seem to find it. I want my blob-URL to be C:\Windows\TEMP\image.png so i can then use it like this:

```
<img src="C:\Windows\TEMP\image.png"/>
```

EDIT:
I don't want to hardcore this temp path cause i have no idea if it will always be the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following JavaScript is just invalid:

```js
var tempPath = "C:\Windows\TEMP\";  // look at code highlighting
console.log(tempPath); // and at the result of execution
```

The problem is that `\` backslashes should be escaped in JS strings.
You need to escape backslashes this way:

```js
var tempPath = "C:\\Windows\\TEMP\\";
console.log(tempPath);
```

In order to achieve this using Razor, you can do the following:

```
var tempPath = "@HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Path.GetTempPath())";
```